# Invalid TLD/Registration Period Supplied for Domain Registration in WHMCS API on ipad

Tags: whm, whmcs

I am using WHMCS API for one of my application. Now when users oders a domain related product from my control panel, which is communicating with the WHMCS through the API from IPAD it is showing the error

"Invalid TLD/Registration Period Supplied for Domain Registration".

I searched and found that the error is usually because of some mistakes like Registration periods not specified for the selected domain etc. But this application works correctly on every other desktop browsers and the domain is registered successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally that message means you've not selected a period for which you've entered a price in the domain pricing section - a common mistake of it defaulting to 1 year, and the TLD requiring a 2 year minimum

If you're only seeing it on one browser/device, then it's likely an issue with the device/browser and you should bin it immediately and get something that follows standards ;)

Alternatively you might find specifically selecting a period rather than letting the browser say it's selected one but hasn't done so will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs -strange enough- when you have no contact person + mail address setup for that client.